# Crear comandos personalizados Linux pero sin la función alias

Tags: linux

Espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje linux y estoy practicando la creacion de comandos personalizados pero quiero hacerlo sin la función alias.

Que metodo o funcion puedo usar que no sea el alias?

Por ejemplo, me gustaría crear un comando que liste los directorios, como lo hace el comando predeterminado 'ls' pero sin usar la función de alias listar = 'ls'

Comment: Hellow friend, this is a spanish site, please translate your question to help you.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenid@ a SO! Lo primero que diría es que linux no es un lenguaje. Linux es formalmente un núcleo para un sistema operativo *como UNIX* (como GNU o Hurd o BSD o Android o algún otro). En lenguaje coloquial, la gente lo utiliza como "plataforma"... pero en todo caso, no es un lenguaje.

Luego, una forma sencilla de hacer lo que pides es crear un script (para bash? U otro intérprete que consideres como python, perl, etc etc) que haga eso que quieres y lo colocas en un directorio que forme parte del PATH de los usuarios de tal forma que lo puedan ejecutar sin tener que indicar la ruta completa. La ruta standard para poner este tipo de scripts es `/usr/local/bin`. Así que si lo que quieres es una forma rápida de poder hacer `ls -la`, digamos que queremos que sea `lsla` la forma de llamarlo:

```
sudo vi /usr/local/bin/lsla
```

Colocamos esto en el archivo:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -la
```

La primera línea indica el intérprete que se debe usar para ejecutar el archivo. Como esto es linux, las extensiones de los archivos no tienen ningún significado (podrías colocar que un archivo es `.py`, lo tratas de ejecutar y va a fallar). Guardas el archivo y sales.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/lsla
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 sep  1 13:36 /usr/local/bin/lsla
```

Y ya con eso lo podemos usar?

```
$ lsla
bash: /usr/local/bin/lsla: Permission denied
```

Nope... todavía no es ejecutable. Así que convirtámoslo en ejecutable por cualquiera y volvemos a intentar:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lsla  
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/lsla
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21 sep  1 13:36 /usr/local/bin/lsla
$ lsla
total 22444
drwxr-xr-x 11 blah blah    4096 mar 18 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 91 blah blah    4096 ago 31 18:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 blah blah    4096 jul 12  2020 apache.git
.
.
.
```